# How to extract data from google sheets using uipath

Tags: record, uipath

How do I read data?

Out of 3 columns A, B, C I want to get data from column 'A' from 1 to 24.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple task. It would be better if you take the time to solve the UiPath [video tutorials](https://academy.uipath.com/static-page/5) with Q&A that are completely free.

But to solve your question. Just create an `Excel Application Scope`. Then add the `Read Column` activity. Here set the correct `SheetName` and the correct `StartingCell`. The `StartingCell` needs to include the header column as well. This will be automatically removed when its reading. Also create an output variable `OutputTable`.

Now you get that `OutputTable` filled with all your entries and you are able to use it.

[image]